# Memcached exits when I load my java server

Tags: java, ubuntu, memcached

Strange issue, memcached exits as I load my java based server. I first load memcached using

`sudo /usr/bin/memcached -m 128 -p 11211 -U 11211 > memcached.log 2>&1 &`

The I load my java server
`sudo nohup java -classpath /home/ubuntu/mCruiseOnServer_lib/ -jar /home/ubuntu/mCruiseOnServer.jar 10.112.75.51 > mCruiseOn.log 2>&1`

memcached terminates just after my java server loads. I wonder why. The java server uses sockets and multithreading, and memcached. It uses it own port and does not try to use 11211.

Edit : I used the -d option and the nohup command. This helped run memcached without interruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try running memcached as a daemon?

```
sudo /usr/bin/memcached -d -m 128 -p 11211 -U 11211
```

Comment: The sudo thing in memcached messes up the reporting. Gives a bunch of warnings that are useless. So I would not recommend the sudo. The memcached guys too dont like running as root or sudo. The daemon is a good idea. I have tried it but it still exists.